# How to stream video to chrome html with gstreamer

Tags: html, google-chrome, video-streaming, gstreamer, chromium

I've been trying to stream webcam with g-streamer to chrome with http. Many approaches I found online only works with FireFox for some (compatibility?) reasons. As far as I know, video tag in html is browser based so it should be something with chrome.

I found this simple example on Github
https://gist.github.com/tetkuz/0c038321d05586841897
 and when I set it up. I got ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE on chrome client side. Is there other approach from gstreamer(which I'm not so familiar with) to stream video in the protocol that chrome can handle?

Comment: As the comments state in that example, no HTTP response is being set.  I don't know if there's a way to do that directly in gstreamer, but it's trivial to do with something like a small Node.js script which pipes the gstreamer data through to the browser.  I've used that method with FFmpeg in the past.